# Error al consumir WCF por ChannelFactory C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webservice, wcf

Este es mi contrato:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ILoginNetSSO
```

Esta es la manera en la que lo invoco desde el método `page_load`:

```
BasicHttpBinding myBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
EndpointAddress myEndpoint = new EndpointAddress("https://google.com.mx/Login.IT.Web.Servicios.SSO/LoginNetSSO.svc");
ChannelFactory<ILoginNetSSO> myChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<ILoginNetSSO>(myBinding, myEndpoint);
ILoginNetSSOwcfClient1 = myChannelFactory.CreateChannel(myEndpoint);
```

Me genera este error:

> El nombre del tipo o del espacio de nombres 'ILoginNetSSO' no se
>   encontró (¿falta una directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?)

Cabe mencionar que la dirección no es la real, pero aun consumiendo la dirección real genera el mismo error, el servicio lo consulto mediante un explorador web y me muestra los métodos.

Answer (score 0):

Intentalo de esta manera:

```
var binding = new WSHttpBinding
        {
            Security = { Mode = SecurityMode.None },
            ReaderQuotas = { MaxStringContentLength = Int32.MaxValue },
            MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2097152,
            MaxBufferPoolSize = 2097152
        };

        var endpoint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EndpointAddress"];
        var channel = new ChannelFactory<ILoginNetSSO>(binding, endpoint);

        var proxy = channel.CreateChannel();
```

Saludos